# Dynamic Table that multiplies the numbers of the first column with the numbers of the first row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to build a dynamic table that scales in size with userinput, multiplies the numbers in the first column (1-n) with the numbers in the first row (again, 1-n) and put it in the empty cells of the table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function createTable(){
            var MyTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var groesse = document.getElementById("Input").value;

            for(i=0; i <= groesse; i++){
                var row = MyTable.insertRow(i);
                //adds as many rows to the table as the user wants

                for(j=0; j <= groesse; j++){
                    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
                    cell.innerHTML = "Placeholder";
                    /*adding the cells in the rows and filling them with placeholders for testing*/
                }

            }
            var Reihennummer = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var Zellennummer = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

            for(k=1; k <= groesse; k++ ){
                Zellennummer[k].innerHTML = k   
            //first row gets the numbers 1-n
            }

            for(l=0; l<=groesse; l++){
                MyTable.rows[l].cells[0].innerHTML = l
            //first column gets the numbers 1 - n
            }

           }                    

    </script>
</header>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">

    </table>
    number pls <input type="number" id="Input"><input type="button" onclick="createTable()" value="GOGO">


</body>
```

So far so good.
Now I want to multiply the numbers, here is what I tried:

```
var m = 1
            for(n=1; n<=groesse; n++){
                MyTable.rows[m].cells[n].innerHTML = (m + 1) * n;
                if (n % 10 = 0)
                    m = m+1
           }
```

If I try that, I don't even get a table on the page anymore, it simply does nothing. So the problematic part is the Multiplication of 2 variable cell indices of my table. Hope you can help me here.

edit: to clarify the % 10: it is for a test input of 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line gives a console error – "Invalid left-hand side in assignment":

```
if (n % 10 = 0)
```

To test for equality, use `==` or `===`.

`==` does type coercion, which isn't needed in this case:

```
if (n % 10 === 0)
```

---

A nested loop works best in this situation:

```
for(var m = 1 ; m <= groesse ; m++) {
  for(n = 1; n <= groesse; n++) {
    MyTable.rows[m].cells[n].innerHTML = m * n;
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhp75che/)

Comment: duhhh thanks a lot that helped, but now the loop only repeats for the second row and stops after it, do you have an idea how to change the loop?